# output json with database

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

Sorry for my English. I'm trying to output the data to a database format json. It seems to do everything right, but it is not true outputs. Here is my link which is obtained: http://ksupulse.tk/get_all.php if I did check the validity of the site  http://jsonlint.com/ or http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ get an error.

**get_all.php**

```
<?php 

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

?>

<?php


$response = array();

require 'db_connect.php';

$db = new DB_CONNECT();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM demo") or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    $response["demo"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $product = array();
        $product["id"] = $row["id"];
        $product["name"] = $row["name"];
        $product["detaly"] = $row["detaly"];

        array_push($response["demo"], $product);
    }
    $response["success"] = 1;


    echo json_encode($response);

} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

I've honestly spent so much time searching for this problem, but the answer is not found. All the same, why do I have prints to the database is not json? DB encoded utf_unicode_ci, and the table in utf8_general_ci

Comment: Can you post the resulting output?

Comment: Could you post a snipet of the data it echos?
`json_encode` should create a valid json object (or `FALSE` if it fails). The code looks like it should work.

Comment: Also, please stop use the deprecated `mysql_` api, check out `PDO` or `mysqli` for newer api's that are recommended to use instead.

Comment: @BobBrown Yes, of course. In http://ksupulse.tk/get_all.php output `{"demo":[{"id":"3","name":"123123","detaly":"123123123"},{"id":"4","name":"4444","detaly":"555555"}],"success":1}` if I put a link to the validator, writes **Unexpected token**

Comment: @Jite `echo json_encode($response);` output `{"demo":[{"id":"3","name":"123123","detaly":"123123123"},{"id":"4","name":"4444‌​","detaly":"555555"}],"success":1}`

Comment: That looks right to me, although the human eye isn't a good parser of JSON.  What validator is giving the error?

Comment: @BobBrown validator is output **Unexpected token**, other validator output **URL field is not json**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an extraneous carriage return in front of your { } sequence (which is valid, in itself).

You should not close `?>` and then reopen `<?php` your script after the `header` instruction.
It outputs garbage to the browser. You really want your stream to begin with the `{` first character.

In other words (for @KnightRider) the lines 5-7 of the script should be removed!

```
05 ?>
06
07 <?php
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for answering this is because I could not attempt but have to write my views

Hi, I have checked this which you posted in the comment and JSONlint verifies it as a valid JSON

```
{"demo":[{"id":"3","name":"123123","detaly":"123123123"},{"id":"4","name":"4444‌​‌​","detaly":"555555"}],"success":1}
```

What else do you need?

Comment: See my answer above: the JSON itself is valid, but the PHP script outputs extraneous leading spaces.

Comment: Hi @Gabriel please I am sorry I could not understand, please elaborate and mark the place where the carriage return is present.!

Comment: the file starts in:
`<?php 
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
?>

<?php
$response = array();`

This is wrong. It should be:
`<?php 
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$response = array();`

Comment: @Gabriel i change `<?php header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); ?> <?php $response = array();` on `<?php header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); $response = array();` but it still does not work( validator is output **Unexpected token**, other validator **output URL field is not json**

Comment: And in your output stream, you still have extraneous characters before and after the { } brackets surrounding the json...
If you open your stream with a Hex Editor, you will see that it starts with this sequence: `EF BB BF EF BB BF` before your opening `{`. Maybe remove the `charset=utf8` in the header? because normally, JSON is NOT utf8. It uses a representation of UTF8 characters but should be readable in ASCII.